# Calculate the mean value in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm looking to calculate the mean of `incid_rea` in each month for each department `nomReg`. The dataset i'm working on is:
[image: CSV File]

My main purpose is to get this :
[image: result]

Any ideas how can i achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple aggregation using group by:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = (df.groupBy(F.date_format('jour', 'yyyy_MM').alias('month'), 'nomReg')
            .agg(F.avg('incid_rea').alias('mean'))
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `window` over month,nomReg and call `avg` over that window on incid_rea.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, date_format

df = df.withColumn(date_format(col('jour'),"yyyy-MM").alias("month").cast("date"))
w = Window().partitionBy("month","nomReg")
df = df.withColumn("mean", avg("incid_rea").over(w))
```